# Partitioned Search in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I have been trying to test the new partitioned search function out from Optaplanner v7 release. I implemented a custom SolutionPartitioner according to the example provided in the [documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.0.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#customSolutionPartitioner).

It seems working fine as I can see the scores are improving with each thread (no hard rule broken, soft scores are improving)... however at every merging/reduce step to the main thread it suddenly got hit by a large negative hard scores from a hard constraint which I can't figure out how does it developed and it's hard to debug.

This hard constraint is similar to the 'requiredCpuPowerTotal' rule in the CloudBalance example - simply checking if the allocation has exceeded one's capacity.

This is the output at the end from 2 threads:

- [OptaPool-1-PartThread-2] INFO Local Search phase (1) ended: time
  spent (120000), best score (0hard/-28317medium/4671205soft), score
  calculation speed (1544/sec), step total (60272).
- [OptaPool-1-PartThread-1] INFO Local Search phase (1) ended: time
  spent (120000), best score (0hard/-16medium/3362676soft), score
  calculation speed (1807/sec), step total (112408).

So I am expecting the final score in the main thread to be the sum of those two threads, i.e. 0hard/-28333medium/8033881soft.

But the actual result is very different:

- [main] DEBUG     PS step (229), time spent (120103), score
  (-3458hard/-159medium/10503603soft),     best score
  (0hard/-7837556medium/0soft), picked move
  (org.optaplanner.core.impl.partitionedsearch.scope.PartitionChangeMove@5fe73332).
- [main] DEBUG     PS step (230), time spent (120214), score
  (-3452hard/-160medium/10511701soft),     best score
  (0hard/-7837556medium/0soft), picked move
  (org.optaplanner.core.impl.partitionedsearch.scope.PartitionChangeMove@5dd30a7d).
- [main] INFO  Partitioned Search phase (0) ended: time spent (121216),
  best score (0hard/-7837556medium/0soft), score calculation speed
  (2/sec), step total (231), partCount (2), runnablePartThreadLimit
  (2).

As you can see when the results from two threads reduced to the main thread, there is a -3452hard therefore the main thread has to pick the beginning score as the best score.

Any idea of how could is happen and how should I debug it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you use docs section "5.5 explaining the score" to figure out what's breaking those hard constraints? I suspect one of your hard constraints isn't compatible with your current partitioning strategy.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey for your reply. Checked the doc and tried to implement that code block as in section 5.5 before or after calling the solver.solve() function, but neither of them give me any return. Where should I add that code?

Comment: By the way the problem is resolved... because I have a customised ValueRangeProvider where I forgot to relocate to each partition.